# value is not a member of SparkSession

Tags: scala

Have below code

```
val (one, two) = 
 if(isTrue) {
   (sparkSession.readData(params)
   .withColumnRenamed(....),
   two)
 } else {
    
  .....
 }

object MyData{

   implicit class  ReadSparkData(sparkSession : SparkSession) {

    def readData(params){
     
       ...........
     }
  }
}
```

There's no compilation error, `readData` really exists in code

```
error `readData` is not a member of `SparkSession`
```

I'm confused and not able to get this error, How this error is coming ?

Can anyone suggest ?

Thanks

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. Missing `def` in the `readData` definition. Unless you didn't copy the exact code?

Comment: @GaëlJ, sorry its typo, copying code can give such error ?

Comment: Still doesn't compile.. what is `params` type? Please post the eaxt code you use. Including the imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implicit class `ReadSparkData` have to be imported, as specified in [documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html). Example:

```
import stackoverflow.MyData.ReadSparkData
val result = sparkSession.readData("")

package stackoverflow {
object MyData {
  implicit class ReadSparkData(sparkSession: SparkSession) {
    def readData(params:String) :String = {
      ""
    }
}}}
```